# Absolute Jumps - Unexpected Behavior

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I was trying to work out how to jump to absolute addresses, and stumbled upon the FF 26 opcode, or "jump [addr]". I tried to use it in Turbo Debugger, and found a peculiar problem: The absolute jump never actually gets me to the address that I specify. I tried explicitly specifying cs as the segment, even though cs and ds point to the same segment in my tests so [addr] should be the same as cs:[addr]. Just to clarify, the jumps are still absolute. Using the same operand with jump from a different location still got me to the same place. The problem is that the locations I reach with these absolute jumps seem to have no connection whatsoever to the memory locations I specify in the operands. I have attached a few screenshots from Turbo Debugger.

The top line shows the instruction used, where I tried explicitly specifying the segment register.
[image: The top line shows the instruction used, where I tried explicitly specifying the segment register.]

[image: The result of the first instruction. As you can see, I jumped to address [20CD] instead of [0000].]

The second attempt, this time jumping to [0002].
[image: The second attempt, this time jumping to [0002].]

The result of the second attempt. As you can see, I reached [9D7D] instead of [0002].
[image: The result of the second attempt. As you can see, I reached [9D7D] instead of [0002].]

Any explanation as to what I got wrong about absolute jumps and why they get me to the wrong places will be appreciated. Also, I will eventually use this in 8086 code. If this works differently in 8086, can you explain how it differs?

Comment: Is there any way to perform an absolute jump, then?

Comment: Wasn't that clear? `jmp addr`. Your last screenshot shows one: `jmp 9D88`

Comment: Then we have different interpretations for the word "absolute". jmp addr assembles with different operands depending on where it is performed. If you look at the assembled opcode and operand you will see that it changes when you do it from different places. I am looking for a jump that is absolute even in the machine code level.

Comment: I do not understand your question: *"I will eventually use this in 8086 code. If this works differently in 8086, can you explain how it differs?"* Your code *is* 8086 code.

Comment: There is no such thing as a near absolute JMP. You can do a near relative JMP. If you use far ptrs then yes you can do absolute, direct jumps. You can simulate an absolute near JMP by pushing the 16-bit near address on the stack and then doing a `ret`. Something like `push 0x1234` followed by `ret` (This type of immediate push is only available on 80186+). If you need it to work on 8086 then `mov ax, 0x1234` `push ax` `ret`. 0x1234 is an arbitrary address. It could be a label etc.

Comment: `jmp cs:[0x0000]` is actually a near indirect absolute JMP. In this case the 2 byte (16-bit address) is read from memory address CS:[0x0000] and then the JMP is made to the address that was read. It will perform the JMP within the current _CS_ segment. `jmp [0x0002]` is the same as saying `jmp ds:[0x0002]` (_DS_ is implicit here). The address this time is read from the memory address DS:[0x0002]. It will then perform the JMP within the current _CS_ segment to the address that was read from that memory location.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Doesn't 8086 allow `jmp ax` (register-indirect)?  That's obviously better than pushing `ax` and then running `ret`, especially if you also care about modern CPUs with a return-address predictor stack which you'd break by using a `ret` without a matching `call`.  `mov ax, 0x1234` / `jmp ax` is also only one byte longer than `push imm16` / `ret`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Since the bottom of the question seemed to imply 8086 there was no branch or return prediction on 8086 (or 80186). I originally preferred the push imm/ret because it was supported on 80186 and it didn't require a register. As I said I was suggesting "simulation". I could have suggested an indirect absolute jump for the 8086 only solution. Had I given the comment any thought I would have suggested `jmp [bx]`. `jmp [ax]` isn't valid addressing mode on 8086. The reality is that, what I was really thinking about this Q: I'm unsure why JMP near relative isn't an option.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I wrote `jmp ax`, not `jmp [ax]`.  Register-indirect, not memory-indirect, since the opcode is `jmp r/m16`.  That seems best if you have to clobber a register anyway.